¿Alguién me pueden ayudar con entender esta oración muy confusa?
Esta encontré en un libro sobre la historia de la República Dominicana.

Aunque no fuese más que por lo que su conocimiento tiene de
aleccionador para los pueblos y los gobernantes en iberoamérica.

Ni tengo idea como se traduce al inglés.

Solamente traés la subordinada. Te falta la otra parte, campeón. Sería "a pesar de que no sea más que por lo aleccionador de su conocimiento...". Pero de nuevo, sin la parte principal la oración nunca va a tener sentido.

Can you please post the full sentence?

“Even if only for the instructive value of its knowledge for the peoples and rulers in Latin America.”
